# ANTLR 4: no viable alternative if predicate used

Tags: antlr4

input

(001)

```
grammar G;

message
    : '(' seqnum ')'
    ;

seqnum
locals [int i = 0;]
    : ( {$i == 3}? DIGIT {$i++;} )+
    ;

DIGIT
    : [0-9]
    ;
```

Rule message produce no viable alternative:

```
[@0,0:0='(',<2>,1:0]
[@1,1:1='0',<3>,1:1]
[@2,2:2='0',<3>,1:2]
[@3,3:3='1',<3>,1:3]
[@4,4:4=')',<1>,1:4]
[@5,5:4='<EOF>',<-1>,1:5]
line 1:1 no viable alternative at input '0'
```

If rewrite rule 'message' as

```
message
    : '(' DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT ')'
    ;
```

It solves the problem.
Why I get the error in the first case?

Comment: There is no error if I use the next rule `seqnum
        locals [int i = 1;]
            : ( {$i <= 3}? DIGIT {$i++;} )+
           ;` However I need the exact match to n (3 in this case) digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your predicate says "only match the following if `i` is exactly 3". Since `i` is initially 0, the predicate means *no* `DIGIT` will ever be matched.

A general rule in ANTLR is to only use predicates when *absolutely necessary*, as they can impose significant performance overhead and are difficult to debug when something goes wrong.

Edit: Your predicate is the equivalent of the following in Java:

```
for (int i = 0; i == 3; i++) {
    // do this 3 times
}
```

Comment: Tnank you! Could you provide the ANTLR equivalent to regexp's `\d{2,3}` and `\d{3}`? Or the only way is `(DIGIT DIGIT | DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT)` for the first and `DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT` for the second?

Comment: Best equivalent to `\d{2,3}` would be `DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT?`. Best equivalent to `\d{3}` would be `DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT`.

Comment: _Best equivalent to \d{2,3} would be DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT?_ It's statement or question? As I get `line 1:2 missing INT at '<EOF>'` for input `12` and rule `seq: INT INT INT;`
So for regexp `\d{1,4}` do I need the next rule `(DIGIT | DIGIT DIGIT | DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT | DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT)`?

Comment: It was a statement. Best equivalent to `\d{1,4}` would be `DIGIT (DIGIT (DIGIT DIGIT?)?)?` (which should now be enough examples to construct any lower/upper bound).